# Creating a vector within a loop in R

Tags: r

I have created this loop to calculate the number of prime factors for 1000 numbers from 1,000,000,001 to 1,000,001,000.  So I have 1000 data points for "sum" and for "omega". How do I get these data points into vectors?

```
j=1
r=1000
while(j<r+1) {
  sum=1000000000+j
  omega=omega(sum)
  print(sum)
  print (omega)
  j=j+1
  }
```

Comment: Before the `while` loop, instantiate `vec <- numeric(0)`. When you find something you want to store, then `vec <- c(vec, my_new_number)`. (BTW, while ["naming variables" can be a very hard thing to do well](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/19836), it's generally bad practice (and easily confusing) to name a variable the same as a base R function, especially one as commonly used as `sum`.)

Comment: And what is the function “omega” that is being used to assign a value to the variable confusingly given the Sam name?